# Is it possible to make a program run on startup by adding it to the "Shell" registry entry?

Tags: windows, shell, boot, login

Is it possible to make a program run on startup by adding it to the "Shell" registry entry? I'm talking about Windows Vista. I want to add to the end of

`explorer.exe`

to make it

`explorer.exe; someOtherProgram.exe;`

Would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend instead adding to registry key:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

or

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`

These will run at startup, after login.  [More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: or just create a task that runs on startup

Comment: Or put a shortcut to the program in the Startup folder in the Start menu.